# QListView won't adjust row height correctly when using custom delegates with different heights

Tags: qt, qt5

I have two custom delegates that implement the sizeHint member function like this:

```
QSize MovieListPosterDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                        const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return {option.rect.width(), 80};
}

QSize MovieListTextDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                      const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return {option.rect.width(), 40};
}
```

If I set the text delegate first, the row height is 40px. If I set the poster delegate first, the row height is 80px. But if, after setting one, I try to change it to another, the row height won't change, e.g.:

First let's set the poster delegate, everything works:

[image]

Let's then change it to the text delegate:

[image]

As you can see there's 40px of extra space that won't go away. And if I try to do it the other way (from text to poster delegate) then it's a mess. I need the view to adjust the row height correctly. How? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are changing item delegate of QListView couple times? Why? This is definitely wrong approach. Item delegate should be set only once. If you want change visualization of one of items than one delegate should handle this in reaction on model value changes!

Comment: A agree with *Marek R*. But for me it would be interesting to know if calling a *QAbstractItemView::reset()* method solves your problem. Could you please try that?

Comment: @Marek R: The model never changes the data. I want the user to be able to change how the items are displayed with a combo box, e.g. "Text" and "Posters + Text", and others.

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, that worked. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `QAbstractItemView::reset()` method to reset the internal state of the view after changing delegate.